Does a matrix ring over a ring satisfy the Koethe conjecture if the coefficient ring itself satisfies the Koethe conjecture?
I just want to know whether the following statement is true or false.
If $R$ is a ring satisfying the Koethe conjecture, then the matrix ring over $R$ also satisfies the Koethe conjecture.
Or is it equivalent to the Koethe conjecture itself?
I will be grateful if you can link to a paper or a book.
